# JQuery .load() and php include()

Tags: php, jquery, include

here's my problem:

on the index.php i have included a config file

```
include("config/config.php");
```

Works great on the main page of course. Now i am loading dynamic content into a Div on the page (later on it will be dependent on query filters):

```
$('#contentPanel').load('include/home.php');
```

in that "home.php" there is need for using a php constant

```
<?php echo PAGE_TITLE ?>
```

the constant is defined in the config.php.

When loading the home.php into the index.php, the script cannot access the config.php anymore, because the file path has changed.
instead of including the config.php in every page again (and changing the file path) is there any other way to solve this?

Comment: This might be of some use: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10691404/php-best-way-to-define-global-constant-available-in-all-files. It looks like there's no easy way to get what you want.

Comment: I thought so, it would mean to "globalize" the config through indefinite number of layers right? I'll just start including the file in every dynamic page -.- But still waiting for suggestions ;)

Comment: Yeah, just remember that if you use a clever solution to not edit every file, it will make it harder for other people to understand where the constants are coming from.

Comment: I found a workaround which is maybe not the best, but working for me. On the index.php i'm loading the config file and then load the constants into a javascript object. That makes it accessible for all dynamically loaded documents. It's working for me, but if you wanna use like a db link, you can't use it anymore....