# Setting a global flag in php, wordpress

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress, recaptcha

I know there were many questions like this, and I've been trying the suggested solutions, but they don't seem to work for me.

I've added captcha to wordpress site, which is being verified by making a GET request in jQuery to `validate-captcha.php`, and returns a message. Works like a charm.

On return I trigger a click of invisible 'submit' button.
To be sure the comment is not posted without captcha check, I need a global flag. I'm setting it in `validate-captcha.php`:

```
global $captchaFlag; //first line
...

} else {
    // Handle a successful verification
    global $captchaFlag; //overkill to make sure it IS global
    $captchaFlag = 1;
    echo ('true'.$GLOBALS['captchaFlag']); //echoes fine
}
```

Then on submit, I've set a filter in functions.php that should check captchaFlag and either submit a comment directly if flag = 1 or verify captcha if flag = 0 or doesn't exist:

```
add_filter("preprocess_comment", "verify_comment_captcha");

function verify_comment_captcha($commentdata) {
    global $captchaFlag;
    echo("<script>console.log('PHP: ".json_encode($captchaFlag)."');</script>");
    echo("<script>console.log('PHP: ".json_encode($GLOBALS['captchaFlag'])."');</script>");
    return null;
}
```

But echoing `global $captchaFlag;` or `$GLOBALS['captchaFlag']` on submit shows that the value is `null` even if it was already set to 1 by validate-captcha.php.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: use DEFINE, see at php.net

Comment: I don't quite get what you want to achieve. Are you triggering the flag using an AJAX call and than want to check it's state on form submit?

Comment: I'm setting a flag in php file, called by AJAX, and I need to make it global to access it from a different php file later on.

Comment: According to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10691404/php-best-way-to-define-global-constant-available-in-all-files, define will not do as I would have to include a file with definition wherever I want to use it or define it at startup, but in this case it has to be dynamic. Tried it anyway and it doesn't work :(

Comment: Nor $_SESSION['var'] works, I now believe it might be wp-comments-post.php firing an error and shutting down before the call is completed, but then why simply checking captcha and sumbitting a comment or echoing an error within the "add_filter("preprocess_comment", "verify_comment_captcha");" works just fine?

Comment: Well, kept it with only javascript verification for now, will get back to the issue later on, when I have time and, maybe, some more knowledge. Thanks for answers anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Globals don't persist across page loads, so that won't work.

You were on the right track using `$_SESSION`, however I suspect that wasn't working for you because you need to call `session_start();` before setting or accessing session variables.

Comment: tried it when I was trying `$_SESSION`, `session_start();` triggers an error 'session already started...headers sent'

Comment: and again, echoing `$_SESSION[var]` from `validate-captcha.php` works fine, but when in comes to checking flag its value is `null`